# any command for react-native just freezes and doesnt do anything

Tags: react-native

I encountered this issue on mac. Tryed everything, reinstalling node, npm, react-native. No luck.

```
$ react-native
```

And it just stands like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Altho its pretty wierd. You need to run react-native commands with sudo.

Example `sudo react-native run`

Edit: If you want to keep your env variables ( example: ANDROID_HOME ), just add `-E` right after `sudo`

Exampe `sudo -E react-native run`

Comment: This is still a bad option. I reinsteled everything and it worked fine without sudo.